# When should an HTTP proxy use status code 502?

Tags: http

[RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) says 502 means: "The server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, received an invalid response from the upstream server it accessed in attempting to fulfill the request."

What exactly counts as an invalid response? Does this include something like a 500 from the upstream server?

Comment: When the response is not HTTP or not parseable.

Comment: @CodeCaster, how can a response to HTTP request be non-HTTP?

Comment: @Opal when there's no HTTP server on the other end of the socket...

Comment: @CodeCaster, ok. Will there by any response in such a case?

Comment: @Opal depends on the protocol of the process that is listening. :) Usually such services do send an error response, which will not be HTTP. For example FTP, SQL, ... :)

Comment: @CodeCaster, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that you have implemented and API that aggregates responses from a couple of third party servers. E.g. you have an application that if asked for info about *lol@lol.com* user will return all the public data about this user from FB, TW and G+.

More or less your API acts as a proxy server. Now if one of these requests fails you have a choice what will be returned to the client. If you want to be explicit about how your application works you can return `502 Bad Gateway` along with message: *Sorry, request to FB failed for whatever reason* and that's all. But you can also hide the implementation details and return a e.g. `409 Conflict` response along with details: *Have no info about the user's FB activity*.

In this particular example `207 Multi Status` would be also very useful.